# Clicking a favorite tag on a tag-filtered /review page does something wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, user-interface, review

I was just checking out posts in the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag on the SO `/review` page. After I got through a bunch, I decided to switch over to the [wicket](/questions/tagged/wicket) tag. I didn't see [wicket](/questions/tagged/wicket) in the **Tag Summary** section, so I clicked on it in the **Favorite Tags** section. This is what happened:

[image: both tags in URL, page only reports first one]

Both tags are present in the URL, but only the first one — the old one — actually gets used for filtering. I remember reading a while ago that the `/review` page's filter is limited to one tag by design, and I'm fine with that.

There are two potential issues here. First, clicking on a tag in the **Favorites** section usually takes you to that tag's questions page, not a `/review` page, so I may have been wrong to try to use it for review purposes in the first place.

If this is by design, then the problem is that the newly clicked tag doesn't replace the previously active tag. When a user clicks a new filter tag, it should replace the existing one in the URL instead of being (uselessly) appended. This behavior does work correctly for tags in the **Tag Summary** list.

If this is not by design, then then problem is that the link isn't going to the right type of page at all.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, was not erasing the tag ...

Comment: to be deployed later